# How to iterate through each row in table and update a column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, iteration, common-table-expression, row-number

I want to update any duplicate string against a client and make it unique by appending a number at the end of it. Following is just a illustration of something that I have.

```
|Id|ClientId|String|
|1 |123     |Apple |
|2 |123     |Apple |
|3 |123     |Orange|
|4 |222     |Grapes|
|5 |222     |Grapes|
```

Due to the nature of data, I had to use the Row_Number() (which I am new to it) to achieve the following result. My question is how can I iterate through the following table and append a number against each client that has a duplicate string so that they are all unique.

```
|Id|ClientId|String|RowId|
|1 |123     |Apple |1    |
|2 |123     |Apple |2    |
|3 |123     |Orange|3    |
|4 |222     |Grapes|1    |
|5 |222     |Grapes|2    |
```

What I want the end result to look like

```
|Id|ClientId|String   |RowId|
|1 |123     |Apple 1  |1    |
|2 |123     |Apple 2  |2    |
|3 |123     |Orange   |3    |
|4 |222     |Grapes 1 |1    |
|5 |222     |Grapes 2 |2    |
```

If it helps following is my sql:

```
patternsWithNumbers AS
(
    Select row_number() over (partition by ClientId + String order by Id asc) AS RowId,
            id,
            t1.*
    from tableName t
    inner join table 2 t2 on t2.ClientId = t1.ClientId and t2.String = t1.String
)
```

Comment: Out of interest, is it imperative to do this in SQL?  This is the kind of task I'd just get Talend to do, purely because it is pretty much built to make stuff like this so easy.

Comment: Hi @ChrisJ I had the same thoughts of just using Linq in a console app to do this. But unfortunately I have to do it in SQL. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: This question has a select statement that looks like it would be useful in finding a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401710/query-that-would-count-and-increment-the-number-of-duplicate-instances-of-that-r

I don't have a SQL environment to test the DCount function (only MySQL), but it looks like it's on the right tracks

Comment: Don't iterate in SQL...SQL is a set based language, not linear.  One query will solve this without iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your query in a CTE like below:

```
; with cte as 
( select id,clientid,string,
row_number() over(partition by clientid, string order by id asc) r
from tbl)


select 
    c1.id,
    c1.Clientid, 
    CONCAT(c1.String, case when c2.id is not null then cast(c1.r as varchar(100)) else null end),
    c1.r
from cte c1 
left join cte c2
on c2.r>1
and c1.string=c2.string 
and c1.clientid=c2.clientid
order by id asc
```

<kbd>**[see working demo](http://rextester.com/MYHHK77776)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

The following query calculates `rowid`:

```
  select t.*,
         (string +
          (case when count(*) over (partition by clientid, string) > 1
                then cast(row_number() over (partition by clientid, string order by id) as varchar(255))
                else 0
           end)
         ) as new_string,
         row_number() over (partition by clientid, string order by id) as rowid
  from t
```

Use an updatable CTE to change the table:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by clientid, string order by id) as new_rowid,
             count(*) over (partition by clientid, string) as cnt
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set rowid = new_rowid,
        string = string + cast(new_rowid as varchar(255))
    where cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would slightly modify Gordon's answer, so that first only product names are changed:

```
UPDATE t
SET
string = string + ' ' + CAST(t2.item_id AS VARCHAR(255))
FROM
(SELECT t.id,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY clientid, string ORDER BY id) AS item_id,
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY clientid, string) AS item_count
FROM t)
t2 
INNER JOIN t
ON t.id = t2.id
WHERE t2.item_count > 1
```

Then it is easy to just to add item number for the client (of course in real life you possibly have also order_id or something like that, which is needed to included in both of these queries?):

```
UPDATE t
SET
RowId = row_id
FROM
(SELECT t.id,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY clientid ORDER BY id) AS row_id
FROM t)
t2 
INNER JOIN t
ON t.id = t2.id
```